# LINQ in child AppDomain

Tags: .net, linq, appdomain, jit

Do anybody have an idea, why JIT compilation of a LINQ expression takes more time in child AppDomain then in the default AppDomain? Up to 4 times longer.

Comment: Please provide your benchmarks code

Answer (score 1):

While without actual profiling I can only make the following guesses

1. There is a small amount of overhead creating a new AppDomain
2. The child AppDomain will have to reload all of the necessary assemblies again.
3. If you are then copying the expression back to the parent AppDomain then you'll be hit with the serialization cost.
4. If you are passing back a compiled lambda method, then you'll get hit with the cost of loading the dynamic assembly into the parent AppDomain.